# Add plugin after grid has loaded

Tags: extjs

Is there a way to add plugin for a grid after the grid has loaded in extjs?
I have trouble where I use extjs designer tool to create a grid; however, there's no option in the designer tool where i can specify the plugin. I'd like to find a way to do it programmingly, anyone has any idea how would I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `addPlugin` method in ExtJS5
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-addPlugin